# What's the meaning of this simple SQL statement?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am new to T-SQL. What is the meaning of the following statement?

```
BEGIN 
    UPDATE table_name 
    SET a = ISNULL(@f_flag,0) 
END
```

Answer (score 3):

- Begin, End: The Begin and End is not needed.  It identifies a code
  block, usefull if more that one statement.
- UPDATE table_name: Update the data in the table "table_name".
- SET: Keyword, start the comma delimited list of column - value pairs
  to update
- a = : a is the column mame, to value to the right of    the = is what
  value will be used
- ISNULL(@f_flag,0): The value to assign. In this case the IsNull checks the value of the @f_flag variable, and if it is null, then use a 0.

*Note: that there is no "WHERE" clause here, therefore, all rows in the table will be updated.